# MediaPlayer Error (1,-2147483648) and VideoView Error 1,-2147483648

Tags: android, video

ı am trying to play video on Emulator. I uploaded multiple videos. But one of them is playing and the others not. ın fact, the way ı uploaded is the same. I am getting the error "Can't play this video". How can ı fix this?

```
        Uri video1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + "com.jsupport.listviewimages" +       "/"+ R.raw.den);
        Uri video2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + "com.jsupport.listviewimages" + "/"+ R.raw.de1);
        Uri video3 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + "com.jsupport.listviewimages" + "/"+ R.raw.de2);
       Uri video4 = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + "com.jsupport.listviewimages" + "/"+ R.raw.de3);
```

video list

```
            private Uri[] viduri = {
        video1,
        video2,
        video3,
        video4,
        };
```

where ı create videoview

```
            exerciseVideo = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    exerciseVideo.setVideoURI(viduri[imagenum-1]);
```